# How to get a list of installed apps on Android device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, launcher

I am trying to make a simple Android Launcher. Through a tutorial and some other stack overflow posts I found this method of getting the list of installed apps:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> rawAppList = getApplicationContext()
                                        .getPackageManager()
                                        .queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

However, when I try to run this, I only get a list of 4 apps. The emulator I'm using to test has 14 apps displayed through the default launcher. Ideally, I would be able to see all of these in my own launcher.

I've tried cloning a [git project](https://github.com/SimCoderYoutube/NovaLauncherClone/tree/Lesson3-getAppsInstalled) which gets installed apps in the same way. When running it on the same emulator all 14 apps are retrieved as expected.

So clearly there's something I've done wrong, but I can't figure out what it is. As far as I can tell, the tutorial I watched has no extra steps. There doesn't seem to be any extra steps suggested in any of the other stack overflow posts I've seen either.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are testing on Android 11+, you probably did not add `<queries>` to the manifest. See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility#intent-signature for more.

Comment: This solved it for me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To comply with package visibility rules, you will need a `<queries>` element as a child of the root `<manifest>` element:

```xml
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.action.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Do we need to have 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
as well in the manifest?

Comment: @aleksandrbel: Not for the scenario being discussed here.

Comment: this queries thing is not working for me. I also tried the permission thing by itself with ignoring the warning, it does not work. Also, I tried both of them at the same time it does not work in android 11 or greater. My app works fine in android 10 and less without even using these queries or permission thing all the installed apps listed in list view. Wondering if there is any other solution for android 11 and greater.

Comment: @Yosidroid: You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve].

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your feedback. I have already searched everywhere I got similar none solution posts. I don't think there will be a solution for this bc I read in google documentation that there is a change from android 11 and higher.