# Waze package hidden in android 13

Tags: kotlin, android-13, waze

So, in my android app (kotlin) I used to access the "com.waze" package in order to know if the device had Waze installed. However, ever since I updated my phone to Android 13 it seems like the package is hidden, so I have no way to know if Waze is installed on the device.

Is there any other way to know this? Am I missing something? This is what I am doing:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.waze", PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES.toLong()))
} else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION") packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.waze", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
}
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71143286/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-apps-on-android-device